# Problem understanding binding theory and c-command

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, chomsky, binding-theory

I am reading about binding theory and I have a little problem. The book (1) says that:

```
A binds B iff:

(i)  A c-commands B;
(ii) A and B are co-indexed.
```

and c-commanding is defined as the following:

Node A c-commands node B if and only if:

```
(i)   A does not dominate B,
(ii)  B does not dominate A, and
(iii) The first branching node that dominates A also dominates B.
```

So far so good. But then there are a few examples. One of them is this:

```
Poirot's brother invited himself.
```

Here, according to the author, "brother" is c-commanding "himself" and they are obviously co-indexed.

[image: Tree diagram of the sentence]

But as far as the definition goes, the first branching node for "brother" here is NP and it clearly doesn't dominate "himself". So how can the c-commanding be valid here?

(1) Haegeman, 1994. Introduction to Government and Binding Theory, 2nd edition, page 211

Comment: The first branching node that dominates your NP [Poirot's brother] is IP, not NP. A and B stand for XP, not X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding theory as presented in Haegeman's book has long since been abandoned by most people who study binding phenomena in a serious way. That book presents the traditional binding theory according to Chomsky (1981, 1986). While it may be good to study and learn that stuff to gain the big picture of the development of syntactic theory, be aware that the account of binding you are learning there is just a reference point nowadays. It's validity is defended by almost no one anymore.

I don't have Haegeman's book here with me, so I cannot verify the example in her book. Taking what you give at face value, I can see why it is confusing. But as Alex B. points out, the way to interpret the example is that the relevant NP is *Poirot's brother*, not just *brother*. The first branching node to dominate this entire NP is IP, so the definition sort of works. The confusion stems from the fact that you've got two nouns, *Poirot* and *brother*, and it seems like one of these should be the relevant node for the definition, whereas what is really going on is that the two together form the relevant NP.

Compare your example with a similar example like

(1)  *[His1 sister] invited himself1.

The definition of c-command and condition A of the theory make the correct prediction in this case, because the reflexive pronoun *himself* should be bound in its governing category. Since its binder *his* is embedded inside the NP *his sister*, it does not c-command out of the NP and therefore cannot bind *himself*.

When you learn about the DP-hypothesis (NPs are really determiner phrases, not noun phrases), you will begin to see why the traditional binding theory that is presented by Haegeman (and many others) doesn't really work anymore. On a DP analysis, the possessive determiner *his* heads the subject DP in (1), which means it should be the relevant unit that c-commands out of the subject DP. In other words, if one assumes a DP analysis of noun phrases, the traditional binding theory does not work anymore.

So I think that the greater message is that you should be prepared to experience further confusion and that as you progress to further stages of the development of syntactic theory, you will see that the field has been changing too fast.

Comment: Or, since Chomsky's theories all get abandoned eventually by people who study language seriously, you could abandon them now and go study a theory that doesn't go to all those silly extremes.

Comment: Agreed! But unfortunately, we have to know about the silly extremes. If we don't, we isolate ourselves and become irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be students who do the beta testing. They deserve better.

Comment: I have to admit, i don't really understand how the DP hypothesis is incompatible with G&B-era binding theory. We just say that DPs (and only DPs) are assigned indices and the binding conditions apply to DPs. You say: "On a DP analysis, the possessive determiner his heads the subject DP in (1), which means it should be the relevant unit that c-commands out of the subject DP" - It doesn't 'c-command out', rather, it's the *entire DP* that c-commands the bound reflexive. No problem here.

Comment: @jlawler Do you think physics students 'deserve better' than to study Newtonian physics? Newtonian physics might be *wrong* in the sense that it breaks down in certain instances, but it's clearly worthwhile as a foundational theory with insightful empirical generalisations. Same with the G&B-era binding theory. It's fairly remarkable how much it actually manages to get right, given how simple it is.

Comment: @P. Elliot, if only DPs assign indices, how is it possible for binding to occur inside DPs, e.g. "his discussion of himself"?

Comment: @TimOsborne because syntax is recursive - referential expressions can be embedded inside of referential expressions, and all referential expressions have indices. I.e. i'd assign your sentence (very roughly) this representation: *[DP his1 [NP discussion [PP of himself1]]]2*. As for how this relates to the DP hypothesis, i was too hasty to say that 'only' DPs are assigned indices, which is a controversial position, and entails that pronouns must be DPs too. We can simply say that all referential expressions are assigned indices - which includes DPs, pronouns and reflexives.

Comment: @TimOsborne Oh, and to clear up a possible point of confusion, the way that the binding works in G&B syntax, DPs themselves don't actually "assign indices", indices are assumed to just be given as part of the representation. Referential expressions come with indices attached, basically.

Comment: @P. Elliot, thanks for your clarifications. So the problem is now evident, I think. A possessive like "his" receives an index. We two agree on that. On a DP-analysis, the possessive is the head of the DP, e.g. "his sister". The entire DP should therefore bear the index of its head, right? It certainly cannot bear the index of a non-head, right? For me, this is one of the numerous problems with the DP-hypothesis. The problem do not arise on the traditional NP-analysis.

Comment: @TimOsborne Indices don't percolate up like categorial features - in fact they aren't features of heads at all - they simply come attached to referential expressions. *his* and *his sister* can (and in fact must) receive distinct indices, since they independently refer to two different individuals. Indicidentally, i think it's unlikely that *his* is a head. I'd analyse it as the spell-out of a pronoun + possessive *'s*. It's clear that possessors are phrasal, e.g.: *[the boy from France]'s sister*, so the underlying representation would be something like: *[DP [DP him ]1 's [NP sister]]2*

Comment: It is of course a great deal of fun to argue about angels and pinheads. But none of these are actually phenomena; they mark presuppositions made at one point or another in the recursive history of generative grammar. This is precisely why I prefer McCawley -- he avoids Occam's razor by sticking with the data and detailing every assumption as it's made, noting but ignoring arguments based on other assumptions, which saves everybody a lot of work.

Comment: @P. Elliot, in GB era binding theory, percolation of the index was occurring up to the maximal projection. It had to be, otherwise there would be no way to overcome the confusion expressed by novice66's question. Look at the example. Your explanation requires that one accept a situation where a DP receives an index that is distinct from the index that its head word bears. The NP-analysis doesn't have the problem.

Comment: @P. Elliot, I agree that "the boy from France's" is a phrase, but the notion that one-word determiners like "his", "my", "the", "a", etc. are phrasal is contrary to basic assumptions associated with the DP-hypothesis. I repeat, the NP-analysis is not confronted with any of these problems.

Comment: @TimOsborne Do you have a reference for this index percolation machinery? I don't think i ever encountered that when learning G&B syntax. I can't understand how it would work. In *the man*, the head noun *man* doesn't refer to anything - it's just a predicate - so why would it be assigned an index in the first place?

Comment: @TimOsborne there's no mention of index percolation in Haegeman's 1994 textbook, which is a fairly encyclopaedic reference for G&B syntax. She does however talk about the following condition: "**45b Referential indices: licensing condition**: X can carry a referential index only if it bears an argumental theta role at some level of representation. 
(Rizzi, 1992b: 4)". It's clear that indices don't percolate up from heads, they're assigned directly to referential expressions. I don't see any confusion here, or why percolation would be necessary.

Comment: @P. Elliot, "man" would be assigned an index like other non-referring expressions are assigned an index, e.g. "men", "no man", "every man". I do not have Haegeman's textbook available. The question above implies, however, that that is what Haegeman is doing. Let me nevertheless concede the point. My concession does not remove the problem, though, because the DP-hypothesis necessitates that one accept constellations in which a DP can bear an index that is distinct from the index of its head word D. That seems problematic to me, mainly because the NP-analysis is not faced with this necessity.

Comment: @TimOsborne Apologies for being overly pedantic - i think at this point the comments thread is becoming non-productive, so i'll also concede the point. I'd like very much to have an in-depth conversation about the binding theory elsewhere though. I enjoy discussing this stuff.